# In Django, how do I write a query that filters a date column by a specific day of the week?

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql, date, dayofweek

I'm using Python 3.9, Django 3.1, and PostGres 10.  I have the following query to give me the articles created in a particular date range ...

```
    qset = Article.objects.filter(
        created_day__gte=start_date,
       created_day__lte=end_date
    )
```

What I would like to add is a clause to specify the number of articles created in a date range that were also created on a specific day of the week (e.g. Monday), where the days of the week are represented by integers (0 = Monday, 1 = Tuesday, ... 6 = Sunday).  How do I add a clause that would also filter by the day of the week?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your block of code that is presented in the question.

You can further filter the qset by doing the following:

```
monday_qset = qset.objects.filter(created_day__week_day=2)
```

day of week from 1 (Sunday) to 7 (Saturday).

You can find more details about [this lookup here on django docs.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#week-day)

Answer (score 0):

We can use [**`ExtractWeekDay()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.ExtractWeekDay) ([Django-Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.ExtractWeekDay)) and **`Count()`**:

```
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractWeekDay
from django.db.models import Count


qset = Article.objects.filter(
    created_day__gte=start_date,
    created_day__lte=end_date
).annotate(
    week_day=ExtractWeekDay("created_day")
).values(
    "week_day"
).annotate(
    count=Count("pk")
).order_by("week_day")
```

The output will be something like this:

```
<QuerySet [
    {'count': 1098, 'week_day': 2},
    {'count': 55, 'week_day': 3},
    {'count': 29, 'week_day': 4},
    {'count': 41, 'week_day': 5},
    {'count': 25, 'week_day': 6}
]>
```